# How can Firefox be sped up / made faster?

Tags: firefox, performance, boot

I know that there are *related* questions:

- [how to get firefox to load faster - Windows Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/25223/how-to-get-firefox-to-load-faster-windows-vista)
- [Increase Firefox Speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/26000/increase-firefox-speed)

but both are quite specific to me.

I'd just like to see a list of good tips for increasing FireFox speed generally, especially start-up speed. This morning it took 3 - 5 minutes to start!

Possible answers may include

- Configuration settings
- Memory hungry extensions
- Other tips

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I've the following plugins/AddOns installed:

- Adobe DLM
- AllowClipboard Helper
- ColorfulTabs
- Download Statusbar
- Firebug
- Flashblock
- IE Tab2
- Java Quick Start
- printpdf
- Smart Bookmarks Bar
- Tab Mix Plus
- Spellchecker

Comment: How many plugins/addons do you have installed? Which ones? as CGA pointed out, there might be something seriously wrong with your system, so please also post the specs of it.

Comment: @Bobby @CGA - thanks for the replies. I have: Adobe DLM, AllowClipboard Helper, ColorfulTabs, Download Statusbar, Firebug, Flashblock, IE Tab2, Java Quick Start, printpdf, Smart Bookmarks Bar, Tab Mix Plus & spellchecker.

Comment: Robinson: Can you please create a [new profile following this instructions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) and test if it resolve the issues? If yes, follow [this tutorial on how to clean up garbage](http://www.gettingclever.com/2008/06/vacuum-your-firefox-3.html) and try deactivating AddOns/PlugIns one at a time until FF speeds up.

Comment: @Bobby - yes, that worked! Thanks so much. Do you want to add it as an **answer** so that I can accept it? Important notes: 1. in the first link I had to enter **"fullpath\firefox" -p** in the run command and 2. in the second link the profile folder was in **firefox\defaults** folder.

Comment: Robinson: Did so. Glad to hear that it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if it is your machine or your Firefox profile, please create a new one following [those instructions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows):

```
FullPathToFirefox\firefox.exe -p
```

If the speed is back to normal, it's your profile. From here you can try to [vacuum and clean out the databases](http://www.gettingclever.com/2008/06/vacuum-your-firefox-3.html) to win some speed. If that doesn't help, deactivate one AddOn/PlugIn after another and test the speed again until you find the offending one.

If even the new profile is slow, then there's something seriously wrong with your system.

Answer (score 1):

If Firefox takes 3-5 minutes to start up there is something seriously wrong either with your FF installation or with your system. I'd suggest you remove your current installation and do a clean install of FF. 
If you are adventurous you could try the new FF 4 beta, it's quite snappy and I'm running myself without problems. To get your addons to work you should install the "Addon compatibility reporter" addon.